# Which personal artillery missions will become harder or easier in 9.18?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In the world of tanks 9.18 update SPGs are scheduled to be completely overhauled.

How will this affect personal missions? Will any artillery missions become significantly harder or easier to achieve?

[Note: This patch is live and playable on the NA servers: https://ritastatusreport.live/2017/04/17/world-of-tanks-na-update-9-18/]

Comment: @Close Vote, it isn't developer intent that he's asking about, he's being quite specific asking whether or not parts of the game will be altered (and how it reflects its difficulty).

Comment: @Oak Unless it's playable, it's not allowed.

Comment: @Frank if it's publicly announced it is, because the information is available for everyone (And they're announced all changes https://worldoftanks.com/en/content/docs/918-updatenotes/), it's not speculative if they've given the actual factual changes

Comment: @Oak Nope.  Patch notes change.  Announcements change.  If we cannot play it, it is off-topic.  Period.  That said, it seems like this version was released last week or so, so I don't get the future tense going on.

Comment: @oak This Patch is already live on the North American server, so it is playable. It is not yet live on the EU and RU servers, as I'm a EU player it's future tense for me but our American Friends should be able to answer this based on their experience/statistics

Comment: @Xenox Meta post related to your last comment https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available/5541#5541